# Permanent redirect after removing html extension in htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have these htaccess rules to remove html extension from urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

It works fine but I can still access from the URL with extension. How to make it so that when a user click the url with extension, will be redirected with a permanent (301) redirect to the extensionless url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add the little snippet at the end which indicates it is a 301 redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: tried it but if you try to access the url without extension it will redirect to the one with extension...strange enough :D